# The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm getting the error "The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected." on Drupal 8.9.6.

Here is the function/controller in question:

```
public function getByType(Term $taxonomy_term) {
    $response = new CacheableJsonResponse();
    $response->addCacheableDependency($taxonomy_term);

    $metadata = new CacheableMetadata();
    $listCacheTags = $this->entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('product_option')->getListCacheTags();
    $metadata->addCacheTags($listCacheTags);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($metadata);

    $productOptionStorage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('product_option');
    $query = $productOptionStorage->getQuery()
      ->condition('field_product_variant.entity.field_product_type_', $taxonomy_term->id());
    $ids = $query->execute();
    $results = $productOptionStorage->loadMultiple($ids);

    $data = [];
    $skip = [
      'field_layer_colors',
      'field_product_variant',
      'field_supporting_colors',
    ];
    /** @var ProductOptionEntity $result */
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      $response->addCacheableDependency($result);
      $option = ProductSerializer::serializeEntityReferenceField($result, $skip);
      $option['field_product_variant'] = $result->get('field_product_variant')->target_id;
      $data[] = $option;
    }

    $response->setData($data);
    return $response;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!